# I am trying use reactdatepicker, but I get error message that setHours is is not defined

Tags: reactjs, date, react-datepicker

I know that this set is supposed to execute on Date objects, but even when I execute on the Date object. The reactdatepicker doesn't work at all.

- Line 12:3:   'setHours' is not defined    no-undef
- Line 12:12:  'setMinutes' is not defined  no-undef
- Line 43:9:   'setHours' is not defined    no-undef
- Line 43:18:  'setMinutes' is not defined  no-undef
- Line 44:9:   'setHours' is not defined    no-undef
- Line 44:18:  'setMinutes' is not defined  no-undef
- Line 45:9:   'setHours' is not defined    no-undef
- Line 45:18:  'setMinutes' is not defined  no-undef
- Line 46:9:   'setHours' is not defined    no-undef
- Line 46:18:  'setMinutes' is not defined  no-undef

````
        const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
          setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 16)
        );
        return (
          <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
            showTimeSelect
            excludeTimes={[
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 17),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 18),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 19),
              setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17)
            ]}
            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
          />
        );
      }; ```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should import   `setHours` and `setMinutes` from `date-fns` module

```
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";
```

Comment: setHours should be imported from setHours not setMinutes (thank you pratik - see other answer)

Comment: It was a mistake but the main point is import setHours and setMinutes from date-fns module.@DavidKong

Answer (score 3):

The import is kind of wrong.

```
import setHours from 'date-fns/setHours'
import setMinutes from 'date-fns/setMinutes'
```

setHours should be imported from setHours not setMinutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in extra packge **date-fns** npm

You can simply use **new Date()**

Just an example

```
 excludeTimes={[
    new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours(), new Date().getMinutes())
]}
```

> Note : [new Date().setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and [setHours](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/setHours) imported from **date-fns** are totally different